# What is the correct way that when creating a custom post type assign values to custom fields created with pods framework?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-insert-post, pods-framework

I am trying to create a custom post type input using the `wp_insert_post` function, this custom post type called `game` was created using the pods framework and contains a series of custom fields which I try to give values using the `meta_input key` as follows

Example using `_pods_` prefix

```
$entry = [
    "post_title" => "{$post->post_title} - {$game->number}",
    "post_content" => "... {$id}",
    "post_type" => "game",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "meta_input" => [
        "_pods_game_number" => $game->number,
        "_pods_game_date" => $game->date,
        "_pods_fields" => $fields,
        "_pods_league" => $id,
    ]
];
$game_id = wp_insert_post($entry, true);
```

Example with no prefix

```
$entry = [
    "post_title" => "{$post->post_title} - {$game->number}",
    "post_content" => "... {$id}",
    "post_type" => "game",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "meta_input" => [
        "game_day_number" => $game->number,
        "game_day_date" => $game->date,
        "fields" => $fields,
        "league" => $id,
    ]
];
$game_day_id = wp_insert_post($entry, true);
```

For some reason the meta fields are not saved except for the `fields` field ... Investigating I read somewhere about using the `_pods_` prefix in custom fields but although I can verify that the fields and their correct values are created in the `postmeta` table these are not listed in the form. If on the other hand I try to reference the custom fields without the prefix `_pods_` they are not created, I confirm this by looking for them in the `postmeta` table.

What is the correct way that when creating a custom post type assign values to custom fields created with pods framework?

I appreciate your time

Comment: Prefixes are used to create unique names for fields, in case it collides with WordPress reserved terms and with any other names used by third party themes/plugins. A `_`  prefix means you want the custom field not to appear in Custom Fields metabox in post edit screen. Both you codes looks fine to me and they both should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve using the [add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) function instead of the `meta_input` property of the `$postarr` argument of the [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function, as follows

Instead of this

```
$entry = [
    "post_title" => "Some post title",
    "post_content" => "Some post content",
    "post_type" => "name_of_custom_post_type",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "meta_input" => [
        "some_meta_key" => "Some value",
        "another_meta_key" => "Another value"
    ]
];

$post_id = wp_insert_post($entry, true);
```

I used this

```
$entry = [
    "post_title" => "Some post title",
    "post_content" => "Some post content",
    "post_type" => "name_of_custom_post_type",
    "post_status" => "publish",
];

$post_id = wp_insert_post($entry, true);

add_post_meta($post_id, "some_meta_key", "Some value");
add_post_meta($post_id, "another_meta_key", "Another value");
```

I do not understand the reason why it has not worked for me, when inspecting the result of `$wp_error` I do not get an error, but as I have described in the question when using `meta_input` no values are registered in `postmeta` table